# Django image not found

Tags: python, django

i would like to paste media image into template but i see this:

[image: this image]

When i click on it to show image i see:

```
Page not found
" C:\Users\troll\myprojects\proj\album\media\images/photos/hour.jpg " doesn't exist
```

I see in this address there is something with slashes, some are normal slashes and some are forward slashes - but how to change it?

my settings.py file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'C:/Users/troll/myprojects/proj/album/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Are you using the development server or a web server? Did you enable [static and media serving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/)? Please post your `urls.py` so that we can check.

Answer (score 4):

You should post your settings.py and urls.py for clear understanding,
which version of django are you using?

still i am considering Django==1.9+

your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
# Media files
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\', '/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', admin.site.urls),

]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) # just after your urlspatterns
```

Create staticfiles directory and run command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and make sure in your templates(form) you have wrote this enctype="multipart/form-data".

```
<form action="{% url 'index' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

try to debug (print) your path of image

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to edit my urls.py;

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include("main.urls")),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]

urlpatterns = urlpatterns+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and my media root looked like;

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```